# Append a new value to a json column type in Rails/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a attribute on my `Share` model called `transaction_ids` which has a column type of `:json`. All I need it to do is hold a list of transaction ids which will keep track of the history - so it can be "followed" over time.

When first creating the Share, I simply add the current `@transaction.id` to it. Works fine. It simply adds something like `"54"` to the column.

```
@number_of_share_numbers_to_create.times do |i|
  Share.create(
    owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
    captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
    company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
    share_number: @latest_share += 1,
    transaction_ids: @transaction.id.to_json # => "55"
  )
end
```

What I'd like to do now is, if this Share is involved in another transaction, just to append that id to it. For example, when a Share changes owners, I use this code to update the owner. I'd like to add that we append the latest transaction id to the column.

```
@share_numbers_on_cap.each do |share|
    share.update_attribute(:owner_id, @buying_shareholder.id)
    # TODO append @transaction.id to share.transaction_ids so we capture the history of this share for later. 
end
```

**Some questions I'm struggling with:**

1. I haven't actually defined a JSON structure anywhere so I'm
   wondering if I can use `<<` or `.push()`?
2. Is it OK that when creating the shares I just end up with for example, `"50"` as the attribute for `@share.transaction_ids`?
3. What if for some reason a share doesn't have any transaction ids - could we just append the latest one then?

Comment: I don't see any key value pair for transaction_ids in the use case described by you so why don't you use an array column type?



If you were to use an array column type, you can define [] (empty array) as default value for your column, then you can call push that will handle appending even if you don't have any transaction_ids.



Let me know if I am missing something in the problem described by you.

Comment: This makes sense, will try this out!

Answer (score 0):

First: Try to make sure you use an **array for transaction_ids**. In your example you just cast the "transaction.id" as json, which is just a String. It should be no problem as you said transaction_ids is a json column, Rails ActiveRecord takes take of converting it into a json string when saving to the DB.

```rb
@number_of_share_numbers_to_create.times do |i|
  Share.create(
    ...
    transaction_ids: [@transaction.id]
  )
end
```

Then you can append it via various methods, your update_attribute is the most fastest, as it skips validations and before actions.

```rb
@share_numbers_on_cap.each do |share|
 ... 
 share.transaction_ids += [transaction.id]
 share.save

 # or also via update_attribute:
 t_ids = (share.transaction_ids || []) + [transaction.id] 
 share.update_attribute :transaction_ids, t_ids
   
end
```